# Unity The type 'TitleAnimScript' conflicts with the type 'TitleAnimScript'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying call a function from a script on another game object to play an animation clip, but it gives me the following error:

> The type 'TitleAnimScript' in 'c:\Users\ruanv\Documents\Unity
>   Projects\Project_MathNinja\Assets\Scripts\TitleAnimScript.cs'
>   conflicts with the imported type 'TitleAnimScript' in
>   'Assembly-CSharp-firstpass, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in
>   'c:\Users\ruanv\Documents\Unity
>   Projects\Project_MathNinja\Assets\Scripts\TitleAnimScript.cs'.
>   [Assembly-CSharp]

The error is in this 'SceneManagerScript.cs' script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Animations;

public class SceneManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject mainMenuButtons;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject levelSelectButtons;

    private TitleAnimScript titleAnimScript;

    void Start()
    {
        // adsf
    }

    public void QuitApp()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    public void LevelSelect()
    {
        mainMenuButtons.SetActive(false);
        titleAnimScript.playAnimClip();
        levelSelectButtons.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

And this is the 'TitleAnimScript.cs' script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Animations;

public class TitleAnimScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator titleTextAnim;

    void Start()
    {
        titleTextAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void playAnimClip()
    {
        titleTextAnim.SetTrigger("playClip");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, it seems restarting Unity fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've made a copy of your TitleAnimScript in a reserved folder. These reserved folder will compile to a sperate DLL called, as you could guess, Assembly-CSharp-firstpass. They're created as two separate projects, which is why the IDE won't pick it up as an error, but because you're referencing Assembly-CSharp AND Assembly-CSharp-firstpass, the solution is seeing two versions of TitleAnimScript.

Check your [reserved folders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html), as described on this page, for any second occurrences of your TitleAnimScript. It could be that you just accidently copied it across at some stage.

For a quick refernce, the folders are:

- Editor
- Editor Default Resources
- Gizmos
- Plugins
- Resources
- Standard Assets
- StreamingAssets